# how to call phtml file in static block?

Tags: forms, phtml, static-block

I have created phtml file,

app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Contact/templates/inquiry.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
/** @var \Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm $block */
?>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Full Name">Full Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="company name">Company Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="companyname">
  </div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email id">Email Id:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emailid">
  </div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="contact number">Contact Number:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contactnumber">
  </div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="product name">Product Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productname">
  </div>

<div class="form-group">

  <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
</div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
</form>
```

and call this file in a static block in the backend

```
<p>{{store url="inquiry-page"}}</p>
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="porto/Magento_Contact/inquiry.phtml"}}
```

but only `<p>{{store url="inquiry-page"}}</p>` is working. Phtml block in not calling up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this piece of code in your static block.

```
{{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="inquiry.form"  template="Magento_Contact::inquiry.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

For Example You can use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template class to call phtml files

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Vendor_Module::myfiles/myfile.phtml"}}
```

To call advanced form use Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Advanced\Form block class.

```
{{block class="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Advanced\Form" name="block_name" template="Magento_CatalogSearch::advanced/form.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call phtml file on CMS Static Block like below

```
{{block class="Block Name" template="Vendor_Module::phtml_file_name"}}
```

So, in your case it might be

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Contact::inquiry.phtml"}}
```